# Grouping and sorting nested collections in Groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy, collections

I have the following POGO:

```
class Widget {
    String name
    Integer order
    // lots of other fields

    Widget(Integer order) {
        super()
        this.order = order
    }
}
```

I have a `List<Widget>` and am trying to put them into a `List<Set<Widget>>` where they are grouped by the `order` field. So if I have 3 widgets with the following respective orders: `{ 3, 1, 2 }` then I would have an outer `List` of size 3 and each element in that list would be a `Set` of size 1. I could manually produce this in code via:

```
Widget w1 = new Widget(3)
Widget w2 = new Widget(1)
Widget w3 = new Widget(2)

// Now sort them by order manually:
Set<Widget> firstOrderWidgets = []
firstOrderWidgets << w2 // order = 1

Set<Widget> secondOrderWidgets = []
secondOrderWidgets << w3 // order = 2

Set<Widget> thirdOrderWidgets = []
thirdOrderWidgets << w1 // order = 3

List<Set<Widget>> sortedCorrectly = []
sortedCorrectly << firstOrderWidgets    // All widgets w/ order = 1
sortedCorrectly << secondOrderWidgets   // All widgets w/ order = 2
sortedCorrectly << thirdOrderWidgets    // All widgets w/ order = 3
```

**So the idea here is that the "unsorted/ungrouped" `List<Widget>` could be quite large, and many widgets could contain the same order.** We want to group all widgets with the same order (order = 1, order = 2, etc.) into the same inner `Set` and then add those sets to the outer `List` in ascending order. So if we were to add a 4th widget to the example above:

```
Widget w4 = new Widget(2)
```

This widget belongs with the other 2nd order widget:

```
Set<Widget> secondOrderWidgets = []
secondOrderWidgets << w3 // order = 2
secondOrderWidgets << w4 // order = 2
```

So I'm trying to write a method that take `List<Widget>` as input, groups them by `order` and then sorts those groups/sets in ascending order. The `order` field is guaranteed to be non-null, but could be any valid positive (1+) integer. My best attempt is causing all sorts of runtime/dynamic exceptions:

```
List<Set<Widget>> sortWidgets(List<Widget> toSort) {
  def groupedByOrder = toSort.groupBy({ widget -> widget.order })

  groupedByOrder = groupedByOrder.sort()

  List<Set<Widget>> sortedList = []
  groupedByOrder.each { order, widgets ->
      sortedList << new HashSet(widgets)
  }

    sortedList
}
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't manage to reproduce your error. It can happen due to how `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented in your `Widget` class. I managed to get a working example using [`@Canonical`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html):

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Widget {
    int order
    String toString() { "Widget(order=$order, ${hashCode()})" }
}

widget = { new Widget(order: it) }

w1 = widget(3)
w2 = widget(1)
w3 = widget(2)
w4 = widget(2)
w5 = widget(2)

allWidgets = [w4, w1, w2, w5, w3]

def sortWidgets(widgets) {
    widgets.sort(false) { it.order }.groupBy { it.order }.values() as List
}

assert sortWidgets(allWidgets) == [
    [w2],
    [w3, w4, w5],
    [w1]
]
```

Comment: Boom - done! Thanks @Will P (+1 and green check). Just FWIW, I specifically needed a `List<Set<Widget>>` and your `sortMethod` above appeared to give me a `List<List<Widget>>`. So I just had to tweak it to iterate through the key/value pairs of the `Map<Integer,Widget>` returned by `groupBy` and explicitly set each value to a set via `toSet()`. But you got me through the hard part (sorting + grouping) - thank you!!!

Comment: @smeeb glad it helped!