# Groovy: group xml segments by ID

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a requirement to create an additional XML tag say myGroup & in that I need to create groups of each ID_Number that comes in from my input.

Here is my input:

```
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>1</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>2</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>2</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>3</ID_Number>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>3</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
```

I want to create groups based on the ID_Numbers so that all the mySegments with common ID come under the myGroup tag as:

```
<myGroup>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>1</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>

</myGroup>
<myGroup>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>2</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>2</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
</myGroup>
<myGroup>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>3</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>3</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<myGroup>
```

I understand that it can be done easily using XSLT but I have to achieve this using Groovy. Pls advise if this can be done by Groovy. I have tried below links but not sure how they can be applied to my case.
[Grouping and sorting nested collections in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622202/grouping-and-sorting-nested-collections-in-groovy)

Comment: I have never used Groovy, but as a scripting language for the Java platform can't you just use Java classes/libraries doing the XSLT processing, like Xalan built into the Sun/Oracle JRE or like Saxon 9, available on Maven?

Comment: It's easier in groovy @MartinHonnen. Tpi, can you come up with an example that's easier to understand? Maybe with root nodes in the XML?

Comment: Tim, I have a field called ID_Number. I need to create groups of the segments which have common ID_Numbers and need to add the extra tag to identify elements with different ID

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `mySegment` elements have a common root element here is an example:

```
def xml = '''
<Root>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>1</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>2</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>2</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>3</ID_Number>
</mySegment>
<mySegment>
<Field1>AB</Field1>
<Field2>AB</Field2>
<Field3>AB</Field3>
<Field4>AB</Field4>
<ID_Number>3</ID_Number>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
<child>
<Field5>AB</Field5>
<Field6>AB</Field6>
<Field7>AB</Field7>
</child>
</mySegment>
</Root>
'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
def root = slurper.parseText(xml)
def newRoot = slurper.parseText('<Root/>')
root.mySegment.groupBy{s -> s.ID_Number.text()}.each{key, value -> def group = slurper.parseText('<group/>'); value.each{v -> group.appendNode(v)}; newRoot.appendNode(group)}
groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize newRoot
```

I guess there are better ways to create the new elements than doing e.g. `slurper.parseText('<group/>')` but the grouping seems to work fine.

If your `mySegment` elements are not children of the root you can find them with `root.'**'.findAll{el -> el.name() == 'mySegment'}` so the grouping would be done with

```
root.'**'.findAll{el -> el.name() == 'mySegment'}.groupBy{s -> s.ID_Number.text()}.each{key, value -> def group = slurper.parseText('<group/>'); value.each{v -> group.appendNode(v)}; newRoot.appendNode(group)}
```